# Display content from OpenCart Module on custom page

Tags: php, opencart, opencart-module, opencart-3

Novice coder here, so please be kind:

I want to duplicate the content from a homepage testimonial module in OpenCart 3.0.2.0 and display it as a single page showing all the testimonials from most recent to oldest.

I have tried duplicating and renaming the module itself (incl. all filenames & contents), but must be missing something as I can't get it to perform as the original module did, let alone customize its output on the front end.

What would be great is creating a module that just takes the original output and then I can format it the way I want through a page template.

Any help would be hugely appreciated, as I'm up against the limits of my understanding now, and the web only provides tantalising glimpses of parts of the answer...TIA

Comment: if you want some help, you need place some code what you have tried, what errors you got and so on...

Answer (score 0):

A Screen shot would be nice that explain what you tried

copying information page or shipping  module or payment module ?

Answer (score 0):

If your goal is to get a dedicated page to show the module content then this might help you. 
You can create an empty information page, use its path in creating a new layout and then you can assign the module to that layout.
This will show the module on that information page and it will look like a dedicated page for that module.